# Gatsby GraphQL not getting images data from Strapi

Tags: image, graphql, gatsby, strapi

I'm using Strapi v.4 and Gatsby v.4.23.0
I use `gatsby-source-strapi` v.2

My **gatsby-config.js** looks like this

```js
const strapiConfig = {
  apiURL: process.env.STRAPI_API_URL,
  accessToken: process.env.STRAPI_TOKEN,
  collectionTypes: [
    {
      singularName: 'article',
      queryParams: {
        // Populate media and relations
        // Make sure to not specify the fields key so the api always returns the updatedAt
        populate: {
          'articleSection': {
            image: {
              populate: {
                data: "*"
              }
            },
            images: "*",
          },
          'categories': "*"
        },
      },
    },
    {
      singularName: 'category',
    },
  ],
  singleTypes: [],
}
```

In Strapi, the Article data model is like this:

[image]

When I explore Strapi GraphQL I can see images data, but the same data are not available in Gatsby GraphQL explorer. I see something like the following:
[image]
As you can see there are no images.

How can I get image data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved with this config

```js
const strapiConfig = {
  apiURL: process.env.STRAPI_API_URL,
  accessToken: process.env.STRAPI_TOKEN,
  collectionTypes: [
    {
      singularName: 'article',
      queryParams: {
        // Populate media and relations
        // Make sure to not specify the fields key so the api always returns the updatedAt
        populate: {
          'articleSection': {
            populate: "*"
          },
          'categories': "*"
        },
      },
    },
    {
      singularName: 'category',
    },
  ],
  singleTypes: [],
}
```